# iPhone. Benefits to using Open GL ES over Core Graphics in a live multiplayer game?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am working on a live multiplayer version of a pictionary like game. It will be like draw something except live with 4 players and not turn based.

is there a benefit to writing my drawing algorythm in OpenGL ES vs CoreGraphics (Quatz 2D) in this situation since i have to be sharing it among 4 players over a network? Or as far as performance goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience in game development... the main reason is performance. Simple 2D game was VERY slow with core graphics and VERY fast with OpenGL ES (1.1).

There was a lot of issues with the positioning of images, strange lines between tiles but at the end we managed to fix it all. In reality, we built a small library of functions very similar to core graphics, only simpler and faster.

Also, portability with OpenGL is simple, with Core Graphics impossible.

Answer (score 0):

CoreGraphics only works on apple products. OpenGL could maybe be adapted to different platforms. I would say that also performances should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Core graphics is not designed for fast, real time drawing or updates to screen. It is designed for high quality artwork, while OpenGL is designed for fast performance, though getting high-quality visuals can be a bit more challenging with OpenGL. It's a trade-off between these of performance and quality of rendered visuals.